# Are there multiple Rydberg constants?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, atomic-physics, definition, physical-constants

I'm sorry if this is a trivial question, I'm trying to understand the Rydberg formula and unsure if there are different values for the Rydberg constant?
According to Wikipedia's articles about [Hydrogen spectral series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series), [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula) and [Rydberg constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant), there are two different Rydberg constants:

- $R_{\infty} = 1.09737 \times 10^7 m^{-1}$ , for heavy metals
- $R_{H} = 1.09678 \times 10^7 m^{-1}$ , for hydrogen

Unfortunately, many other sites like [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/energy-level-and-transition-of-electrons/) and [CODATA](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?ryd) treated Rydberg constant as a single value:

- $R = R_{\infty} = 1.09737 \times 10^7 m^{-1}$

Confusingly, [my textbook](https://books.google.com.nf/books?id=WOS0p8xnD8MC&printsec=copyright&source=gbs_pub_info_r#v=onepage&q&f=false) also treated Rydberg constant as a single value, but says:

- $R_{H} = 1.09737 \times 10^7 m^{-1}$

So are there different Rydberg constants for heavy metals and hydrogen, or is it an incorrect/outdated definition? What is the correct way to understand the Rydberg constant?

Answer (score 1):

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html

quote from here one for the sources of the wiki article

"The reason for the variation of R is that for hydrogen the mass of the orbiting electron is not negligible compared to the proton at the high accuracy at which spectral measurement is done. So the reduced mass of the electron is needed. But for heavier elements the movement of the nucleus can be neglected."

because the nucleus is so light in a hydrogen atom you have to take into account the way it moves but when you have fatter nuclei the movement will become negligible. thats the diffence.

Comment: Thanks! So its correct to treat the constant differently for hydrogen and heavier elements, right?